# how to give XML file from local drive using HTML and VB Script

Tags: html, xml, file, vbscript

[image: HTML GUO pic]

[image: VB script code pic]

please help me for how to select XML file from local drive and give that file path to my VB script code automatically.. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the name or id property of the Input File tag? You can get it from HTML source code.

Below code should work

```
XMLDataFile = <name>.value    Or    Document.forms(0).<name>.value
```

or

```
XMLDataFile = Document.getElementById("<id>").value
```